# How to select a column in with a CLOB datatype

Tags: java, sql, clob

I have a table on my jsp page that will have a column populated by a database column with type CLOB.  I am running into some trouble doing this, and have seen other questions asked about this, but the answers have not worked for me. Here is my statement where comments is a CLOB.

```
   stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT restriction, person, start_date, end_date, comments "
                           + "  FROM restrictions WHERE person = ? "
                           + "   AND (start_date BETWEEN TO_DATE (? , 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE (? , 'yyyy/mm/dd') "
                           + "    OR start_date < TO_DATE (? , 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND end_date IS NULL) " );

        stmt.setString(1, Id);
        stmt.setString(2, StartRest);
        stmt.setString(3, EndRest);
        stmt.setString(4, EndRest);
        result = stmt.executeQuery();
```

And then I will have the columns in a while loop:

```
   while (result.next()) {     
        restrictions = StringUtils.defaultString(result.getString("str_restriction"));
        .......
        // here is where I would get my Clob data from the query.
```

So, basically, I was wondering if there is a way to translate the CLOB in the query, or even in the java code, so it would be usable in my page.

Comment: 2 questions: Which part is the CLOB? restrictions? 2nd: WHY is it a CLOB and not text (or medium/long text)? Not clear from your description

Comment: Thanks for reading.  1. 'comments' is a CLOB, see first paragraph 2. Some (very few) will have very long text in the column.  The table design was not mine, unfortunately, so it is possible it could have just been another datatype when it was created.

Comment: 1. Which trouble do you have? What did you try and which exception did you have? Did you try with getClob()? 2. Why don't you use dates (java.sql.Date instances) instead of strings that you have to parse with TO_DATE?

Comment: 1. ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB, that is the error I get when I run the SQL.  2. I guess I could do that, all works out the same for now (at least until I fine tune the code) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the distint clause of the query, which can't be applied to a CLOB.

Check if the distinct keyword is really needed. Or maybe you could rewrite your query as

```
select restriction, person, start_date, end_date, comments from restrictions 
where id in (select distinct id from restrictions where <original where clause>)
```

PS: next time, include the error message and your database in the question. I've been able to find the problem with a simple google search on "ora-00932 clob".

Comment: Okay, I apologize, my question may have been misstated.  I now have the query running (thanks to your answer), but the result is just (Clob) rather than the actual data behind it.  Any clue on that?

Comment: I fixed a typo in the query of my answer. But if the coments column is a clob, you should use resultSet.getClob() to get it, and the use the returned Clob object to get the contents. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getClob%28java.lang.String%29 and http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html